# Condition for elasticsearch nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

help me please, i have this product documents with nested field "attr":

```
{"title" : "Televisor № 1", "code" : 1, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["1920*1080"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi", "lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : [27]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 2", "code" : 2, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["800*600"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["wi-fi"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : [20]}]},
{"title" : "Televisor № 3", "code" : 3, "attr" : [{"key" : "resolution", "value" : ["640*480"]}, {"key" : "network", "value" : ["lan"]}, {"key" : "diagonal", "value" : [18]}]},
```

How i can select televisors

```
where
resolution IN ("1920*1080")
AND
network IN ("wi-fi", "lan")
AND
diagonal > 20
```

Comment: What does your mapping look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: mapping too long cant post here because limit 840 symbols :(

Comment: I would suggest you to change your mapping to something like this: `{"title":"Televisor № 1","code":1,"attr":[{"resolution":"1920*1080"},{"network":["wi-fi","lan"]},{"diagonal":[27]}]}` - it would be much easier to add conditions on those nested fields